# IOS: touchbegan and touchmoved in two classes

Tags: ios, uiimageview, touch

In my class that I call "one" I have two method for touch: touchbegan and touchmoved.
In this class I alloc an imageview in this way:

```
imageView = [[ImageToDrag alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"machine.png"]];
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(905, 645);
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
```

in this class (ImageToDrag) in .m I have:

```
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // When a touch starts, get the current location in the view
    currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Get active location upon move
    CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    // Determine new point based on where the touch is now located
    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x + (activePoint.x - currentPoint.x),
                                 self.center.y + (activePoint.y - currentPoint.y));

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // Make sure we stay within the bounds of the parent view
    //--------------------------------------------------------
  float midPointX = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds);
    // If too far right...
  if (newPoint.x > self.superview.bounds.size.width  - midPointX)
    newPoint.x = self.superview.bounds.size.width - midPointX;
    else if (newPoint.x < midPointX)    // If too far left...
    newPoint.x = midPointX;

    float midPointY = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds);
  // If too far down...
    if (newPoint.y > self.superview.bounds.size.height  - midPointY)
    newPoint.y = self.superview.bounds.size.height - midPointY;
    else if (newPoint.y < midPointY)    // If too far up...
    newPoint.y = midPointY;

    // Set new center location
    self.center = newPoint;
}
```

so my problem is this: touch recognize method inside ImageToDrag class and not in my main class "one", why? is there a way to recognize touch in each class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `UIResponder` `touchesBegan` method:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. However
>   immediate UIKit subclasses of UIResponder, particularly UIView,
>   forward the message up the responder chain. To forward the message to
>   the next responder, send the message to super (the superclass
>   implementation); do not send the message directly to the next
>   responder. For example,

So add `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` to your `touchesBegan` method (and the other touches methods) for events you want to pass up the responder chain.

You should also implement the `touchesEnded` and `touchesCanceled` methods.